# for each item in array if match do this else if using jvectormaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, jvectormap

I am trying to setup an array of states and if a state or value exists in the array do a function. Below is the actual code i am trying to modify and the "stateRedirects" var is what i am trying to us in the if (code === stateRedirects ) { }...

```
var stateRedirects = [
    'US-TX',
    'US-CA',
    'US-AL'
    // more will be added
]

$('.map').vectorMap({
    map: 'us_en',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: '#0071A4',
    hoverColor: false,
    hoverOpacity: 0.5,
    normalizeFunction: 'polynominal',
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
    onLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
        if (code === stateRedirects ) {
            //do nothing
        }
        else if (code) { //if a state is not specified in var stateRedirects then prevent default
            event.preventDefault();
        }                   
    },      
    onRegionOver: function(event, code){
        if (code === stateRedirects ) {
            //do nothing
        }
        else if (code) { //if a state is not specified in var stateRedirects then prevent default
            event.preventDefault();
        }                   
    },
    onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
        window.location = '/' + code;
    }   
});
```

Per comments i changed it to use [ and ] but can not figure out how to now make it see if the code matches the array in this line `if (code === stateRedirects ) {`

Comment: Is it `stateRedirects` an array? Then please use `[]` instead of `()`, which would result in evaluating to the last value.

Comment: yes it is supposed to be an array but i do not know how to correctly get it to allow me to enter each state and use that variable down in the if statement to see if there is a state name that matches from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Define your array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Array_literals) of state code properly with square brackets. Then use [array.contains functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/1048572), which seems to be what you want.

Comment: i modified the array to use [ and ] but am lost at modifying the if (code === stateRedirects ) to check if the code is equal to any of the items in the array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd linked to a bunch of solutions for that task. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry but i am new to jquery and having a hard time making it see if the code === the array items. I tried making it code === $.inArray(code, stateRedirects) but that did not work. I am trying this if (code === 'US-TX' && 'US-CA' ) but cant get it to work either

Comment: @Aaron - the `$inArray()` function returns the index in the array, or -1 if not found. Your test criteria for your if statement would be: `if ( $.inArray(code, stateRedirects) != -1 )`